# Using h2 database for local development in Google App Engine

Tags: database, google-app-engine, h2

I'm developing a Google App Engine application. In production I'm planning on using Google Cloud SQL, but in  development I wanted to use an h2 database. It works fine when using an in-memory and embeded db (`jdbc:h2:mem/dev`/`jdbc:h2:~/folder/dev`) but not with a server-enabled one (`jdbc:h2:~/folder/dev;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE`), it fails with the following error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.net.SocketException: Permission denied: Not allowed to issue a socket bind: permission denied."; "port: 0 ssl: false" [90031-168]
at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:315)
at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createServerSocketTry(NetUtils.java:193)
at org.h2.util.NetUtils.createServerSocket(NetUtils.java:156)
at org.h2.server.TcpServer.start(TcpServer.java:222)
at org.h2.tools.Server.start(Server.java:455)
at org.h2.engine.Database.startServer(Database.java:672)
at org.h2.engine.Database.open(Database.java:544)
at org.h2.engine.Database.openDatabase(Database.java:222)
at org.h2.engine.Database.<init>(Database.java:217)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:56)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.openSession(Engine.java:159)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSessionAndValidate(Engine.java:138)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:121)
at org.h2.engine.Engine.createSession(Engine.java:28)
at org.h2.engine.SessionRemote.connectEmbeddedOrServer(SessionRemote.java:305)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:108)
at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.<init>(JdbcConnection.java:92)
at org.h2.Driver.connect(Driver.java:72)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)
```

As I understand, this is GAE's limitations playing up.This is stopping me from having easy access to the db while the application is running. Is there a way to circumvent this issue in local server mode only?  I'm curious if there's an alternative to just using a MySql db in dev mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently trying out H2 in GAE too. Standard environment is a no go for me because of mem and writable disk: a combined max of 1Gb with a F4-1G instance.
If h2 embedded mode works, you must be using Flexible as Standard only allows /tmp for write operations.
On the error itself, GAE does not allow listening sockets so no auto-server unfortunately regardless of the type of environment (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/sockets/)